# Is new stack frame created when a by-name block is evaluated or closure is stored in the heap?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have this method:

```
def profiledAction[T](block: => T)(implicit driver: WebDriver):(T, Long) = {
    val startOfDeletion = System.currentTimeMillis
    val result:T = block
    val endOfDeletion = System.currentTimeMillis
    (result, endOfDeletion - startOfDeletion)
}
```

I would like to better understand how exactly passing and evaluation of `block` is implemented in terms of JVM. As far as I understand by-name arguments may have some data associated with it's scope and this we call a closure.
I think that closure is stored in the heap and no new stack frame is created but could you clarify if my understanding is correct?

In other words: I understand how a stack frames are allocated when I call a new method with by-value parameter. Here I am trying to better understand what exactly happens in val result:T = block line execution and where exactly block and it's related closure data is stored till that moment.

Comment: I would assume you would better like to ask how call by name and call by value implemented in terms of JVM??

Comment: Pavel, not exactly. I understand how a stack frames are allocated when I call a new method with by-value parameter.
Here I am trying to better understand what exactly happens in `val result:T = block` line execution and where exactly `block` and it's related closure data is stored till that moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`block: => T` is syntactic sugar for `block: Function0[T]`. A variable of type `Function0` is created and passed (by reference) same way any other parameter would be passed. 
Then, inside the function, when you do `val result = block`, a new stack frame is created, the function is executed, the return value is popped off the stack and assigned to `result`

Answer (score 1):

To better understand by name parameters and their effect on the stack, first lets examine what actually happens to a by name parameter at compile time.

Given this very simplified code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    byName(1)
}

def byName(a: => Int): Int = {
    a
}
```

Compiling it with `-Xprint:jvm` flag, we'll see:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                       jvm]] // SOTesting.scala
package com.testing {
  object SOTesting extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      SOTesting.this.byName({
        $anonfun()
      });
      ()
    };
    def byName(a: Function0): Int = a.apply$mcI$sp();
    final <static> <artifact> def $anonfun$main$1(): Int = 1;
    def <init>(): com.testing.SOTesting.type = {
      SOTesting.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

A by name parameter is just syntax sugar for a `Function0`.

Now lets return to your question:

> I am trying to better understand what exactly happens in `val result: T = block` line execution and where exactly block and it's related closure data is stored till that moment.

It's a method call to `Function0.apply`. Note this can be inlined by the JIT to avoid the cost of the new stack frame, but at least for the first invocations of the block it will incur a new stack frame.

Comment: Thanks, Yuval. Especially for learning the "-Xprint:jvm" usage, I have not tried it before.